# Installing Miniconda on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: anaconda, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to install miniconda on a Raspberry Pi4 (aarch64, PiOS). I downloaded https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh and ran the script. Installation ended with message:

```
Unpacking payload ...
Illegal instruction
```

When I check the content of '/mode/user/miniconda3', I see a 'conda.exe' file here...

Am I doing something wrong or could this be a bug with the `Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh` script itself?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2023-09-12, you need to download `Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh`.

```
sudo wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh

sudo /bin/bash Miniconda3-py39_4.9.2-Linux-aarch64.sh
```

Do not upgrade.

Thanks to [Dougie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/94397/dougie) who provided the answer in [another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/139651/156805).

Answer (score 1):

This apparently a known issue not fixed yet:

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12886

> https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-aarch64.sh currently borked and unable to install on a linux aarch64 env.